# Swift: UIWebView (and WKWebView) failing to present AlertController when view controller is presented and not pushed

Tags: ios, swift

I have this simple app I'm trying to write, where user should be able to us use google search to find images, the problem is that when he uses long press to select a photo, I'm getting an error:
Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

And if I replace the `self.navigationController!.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)` with `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)` in the ViewController everything works fine. Which drives me nuts.

AppDelegate:

```
    let viewController = ViewController()
    let navController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)

    let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    window = UIWindow.init(frame: frame)
    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
```

ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let search = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: Selector("searchImages"))
    self.setToolbarItems([search], animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
}

func searchImages() {
    let searchVC = SearchImageViewController()
    let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: searchVC)
    self.navigationController!.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And finally SearchImageViewController:

```
weak var webView: UIWebView?

override func loadView() {
    let webView = UIWebView.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.view = webView
    self.webView = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let done = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: Selector("done"))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = done

    let url = NSURL.init(string: "http://images.google.com/ncr")
    let request = NSURLRequest.init(URL: url!)
    webView!.loadRequest(request)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func done() {


}
```

Any thoughts will be much appreciated. 
By the way showing normal AlertController works fine (inside `done` function).

Comment: iOS doesn't allow presenting view controller on a view controller that is already presenting. I also came across this issue and the only way out was to push the previous view controller instead of presenting.

Comment: from my experience you can present view controller, and that controller can present another one, done this multiple times before (although using ObjC)

Comment: OK. after overcoming my laziness - i wrote this small app in ObjC, seeing same issue.

Comment: So maybe @AdeelMiraj you were right...

Comment: at least for UIAlertController that UIWebView (or WKWebView) attempts to present... tried presenting my view controller on top of other my view controller modally multiple times - seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Exactly what issue are you having now? Do you see any message in the console when you present the AlertController?

Comment: seeing this error: Warning: Attempt to present <UIWebRotatingAlertController: 0x7fa5609a3800> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fa56082b400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: its like webView trying to present UIWebRotatingAlertController on the parent viewControllers view instead of the one its in...

Comment: UINavigationController: 0x7fa56082b400 - is view created in AppDelegate, and not the nav controller which has SearchImageViewController as root view controller.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are presenting the AlertController?